# Binding data to one o many forms from one view - BadHeaderError at - Header values can't contain newlines ()

Tags: python, django-forms, django-views

I have the following forms to each user profile:

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            widgets = {'gender':forms.RadioSelect,}
            fields = ("username", "email", "is_student","is_professor", "is_executive",)
            model = get_user_model() #My model User

class StudentProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = StudentProfile
            fields = ('origin_education_school','current_education_school',
                'extra_occupation')

class ProfessorProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = ProfessorProfile
            fields = ('occupation',)

    class ExecutiveProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = ExecutiveProfile
            fields = ('occupation', 'enterprise_name', 'culturals_arthistic','ecological')
```

I have an URL which call to my `AccountProfilesView` class based view which create an instance of the previous forms according to the user profile:

```
url(r"^profile/(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$", views.AccountProfilesView.as_view(), name='profile'),
```

My `AccountProfilesView` is this:

I this moment, from the `AccountProfilesView` class based view I am create the different instances of each one of these forms, according to the 
user profile, then, if an user have the `is_student` profile their related form will be generated, and so, of this way to `is_professor`  and `is_executive` profiles

If an user have the three profiles (is_student, is_professor,is_executive ) in one single form will be created or rendered the fields of the three forms associated to each user profile related.

```
class AccountProfilesView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
        # All users can access this view
        model = get_user_model()
        #success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard')
        template_name = 'accounts/profile_form.html'
        fields = '__all__'

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(AccountProfilesView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            user = self.request.user

            if not self.request.POST:
                if user.is_student:
                    profile = user.get_student_profile()
                    context['userprofile'] = profile
                    context['form_student'] = forms.StudentProfileForm()
                if user.is_professor:
                    profile = user.get_professor_profile()
                    context['userprofile'] = profile
                    context['form_professor'] = forms.ProfessorProfileForm()
                    print ("profesor form is", context['form_professor'])
                if user.is_executive:
                    profile = user.get_executive_profile()
                    context['userprofile'] = profile
                    context['form_executive'] = forms.ExecutiveProfileForm()
            return context

        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            self.object = self.get_object()
            context = super(AccountProfilesView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
            user = self.request.user
            # if self.request.method == 'POST':
            if user.is_student:
                context['form_student'] = forms.StudentProfileForm(
                    self.request.POST)
            elif user.is_professor:
                context['form_professor'] = forms.ProfessorProfileForm(
                    self.request.POST)
            elif user.is_executive:
                context['form_executive'] = forms.ExecutiveProfileForm(
                    self.request.POST)
            return context

        def form_valid(self, form):
            context = self.get_context_data(form=form)
            user = self.request.user
            user = form.save()
            if user.is_student:
                student = context['form_student'].save(commit=False)
                student.user = user
                student.save()
            if user.is_professor:
                professor = context['form_professor'].save(commit=False)
                professor.user = user
                professor.save()
            if user.is_executive:
                executive = context['form_executive'].save(commit=False)
                executive.user = user
                executive.save()
            return super(AccountProfilesView, self).form_valid(form)

        def get_success_url(self):
            return reverse('dashboard')
```

And in my template, I have the following small logic:

```
<form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% if userprofile.user.is_student %}

            <div align="center"><i>My Student Profile data</i></div>
                {% bootstrap_form form_student %}
            {% endif %}


            {% if userprofile.user.is_professor %}
                <div align="center"><i>My Professor Profile data</i></div>
                {% bootstrap_form form_professor %}
            {% endif %}


            {% if userprofile.user.is_executive %} 
                <div align="center"><i>My Executive Profile data</i></div>  
                {% bootstrap_form form_executive %}
            {% endif %}

            <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-default">
        </form>
```

From the perspective of show the forms with the fields according to the userprofile, this approach works, the data or fields related to the user profile are denoted or rendered

For example this user have the three profiles  and in the screen of profile in the application, show the three forms:

[image]

But at moment of perform update of such view screen form, (in which each profile have their respective model/table in where their own data are managed) happened the following:

When I click en Save Changes there is an error:

```
File "/home/bgarcial/workspace/ihost_project/accounts/views.py", line 185, in post
        self.request.POST)
      File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/ihost/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 142, in __setitem__
        value = self._convert_to_charset(value, 'latin-1', mime_encode=True)
      File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/ihost/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 115, in _convert_to_charset
        raise BadHeaderError("Header values can't contain newlines (got %r)" % value)
    django.http.response.BadHeaderError: Header values can't contain newlines (got '<tr><th><label for="id_origin_education_school">Origin education institute:</label></th><td><input id="id_origin_education_school" maxlength="128" name="origin_education_school" type="text" value="Universidad de la Amazonía" required /></td></tr>\n<tr><th><label for="id_current_education_school">Current education institute:</label></th><td><input id="id_current_education_school" maxlength="128" name="current_education_school" type="text" value="Universida EAFIT" required /></td></tr>\n<tr><th><label for="id_extra_occupation">Extra occupation:</label></th><td><input id="id_extra_occupation" maxlength="128" name="extra_occupation" type="text" value="Mother" required /></td></tr>')
    [08/Apr/2017 20:21:13] "POST /accounts/profile/luisa/ HTTP/1.1" 500 108206
```

More precisely:

[image]

I think so, is that at the moment of create the form instances of the Django forms, and I denote that the data to be included in the request  and the POST operation, this is not validated of some way

I unknown the traceback error:

```
BadHeaderError
Header values can't contain newlines (got '<tr><th>) .....
```

With any user profile which have the user happen the same behavior, in relation to the fields that are sent in the POST operation, being these of `StudentProfileForm`, `ProfessorProfileForm` or `ExecutiveProfileForm`

Is possible that the error can be in the definition of fields in the ModelForms in my forms.py?

---

**UPDATE**

According to the [@Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) answer I haven't override of `post()` method and my AccountProfilesView is such as follow:

```
class AccountProfilesView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    # All users can access this view
    model = get_user_model()
    #success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard')
    template_name = 'accounts/profile_form.html'
    fields = '__all__'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AccountProfilesView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = self.request.user

        if not self.request.POST:
            if user.is_student:
                profile = user.get_student_profile()
                context['userprofile'] = profile
                context['form_student'] = forms.StudentProfileForm()
            if user.is_professor:
                profile = user.get_professor_profile()
                context['userprofile'] = profile
                context['form_professor'] = forms.ProfessorProfileForm()
                print ("profesor form is", context['form_professor'])
            if user.is_executive:
                profile = user.get_executive_profile()
                context['userprofile'] = profile
                context['form_executive'] = forms.ExecutiveProfileForm()
        else:
            if user.is_student:
                context['form_student'] = forms.StudentProfileForm(
                self.request.POST)
            if user.is_professor:
                context['form_professor'] = forms.ProfessorProfileForm(
                self.request.POST)
            if user.is_executive:
                context['form_executive'] = forms.ExecutiveProfileForm(
                self.request.POST)
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data(form=form)
        user = self.request.user
        user = form.save()
        if user.is_student:
            student = context['form_student'].save(commit=False)
            student.user = user
            student.save()
        if user.is_professor:
            professor = context['form_professor'].save(commit=False)
            professor.user = user
            professor.save()
        if user.is_executive:
            executive = context['form_executive'].save(commit=False)
            executive.user = user
            executive.save()
        return super(AccountProfilesView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('dashboard')
```

And the problem described previously of the error fields in the forms dissapear. Great. But my form in this moment does not saved data of the forms to database.

There is something bad approach in my `form_valid` method?

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem does not have anything to do with forms. In your `post` method, you get the response object from the `super` call but then attempt to set values on it as if it were a dict. You can't do that; that code belongs in `get_context_data`. You shouldn't be overriding post anyway.

Comment: Daniel thanks, I've put the create form instances in the `get_context_data` method. But in this moment the form or set forms rendered, does not save values to database, and the `success_url` is crazy ... Can you check my **UPDATE** please for details about of save forms in `form_valid()` method?  My apologies for the inconvenients

Comment: I've posted a new question about of my new problem just in case that you can give me some orientation http://stackoverflow.com/q/43314269/2773461 I appreciate your help